# std::array : access member of element through smart pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, syntax

I am translating a java program to C++, and the architecture requires me to return a null pointer at certain points.
I have a pointer constructed as such:

`auto p= std::make_unique< std::array< A, 3>>();`

where A is of the form:

```
class A
    {
    public:
        double x = 0, y = 0;

        A(const double x, const double y):
            x(x), y(y)
        {}
    };
```

Now, I would need to set the members through the pointer, so I would think:

```
p[0].x += 1.0;
```

Since `unique_ptr` has the dereferencing `[]` operator, but that fails with:

`error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::unique_ptr<std::array<A, 3ull> >' and 'int')`

I reviewed similar questions, but it is unclear to me if what I want to do is possible. Is the `[]` operator for c-style declared arrays only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the `[]` operator for c-style declared arrays only?

Yes, it's only supported for the array version, i.e. [`unique_ptr<T[]>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), `std::array` is not counted.

You can use `operator*` instead, like

```
(*p)[0].x += 1.0;
```